# Не получается сохранить user

Tags: java, spring

Я получаю данные о user в frontend и передаю на backend.
Данные приходят как нужно и в дебагере видно что данные доходят до метода save(user), но к сожалению user не сохраняется в БД
а в дебагере получаю ошибку "
Код сохранение (service)

```
    public User registerUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    user.setCreated(new Date());
    user.setUpdated(new Date());
    user.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);
    user.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
    user.setLastPasswordResetDate(new Date());

    User registeredUser = userRepository.save(user);

    Random r = new Random();
    Integer integerCode = r.nextInt(999999 + 1 - 100000) + 100000;

    ActivationCode activationCode = new ActivationCode();
    activationCode.setCode(String.valueOf(integerCode));
    activationCode.setUserId(registeredUser.getId());
    activationCode.setCreated(new Date());
    activationCode.setUpdated(new Date());
    activationCode.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);
    activationCodeRepository.save(activationCode);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Hello, %s! \n" +
                        "Welcome to TeamGetter. Your activation code: %s",
                user.getUsername(),
                activationCode.getCode()
        );

        mailService.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", message);
    }

    log.info("IN registerUser user {} registered", registeredUser);

    return registeredUser;
}
```

Код сохранение (controller)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "signUp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    try {
        userService.registerUser(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> Method threw 'org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException'
> exception. Cannot evaluate
> com.teamgetter.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a264c502.toString()"

1)Данные о user приходит с frontend
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)Save user
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3)Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, представить [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Здравствуйте исправил надеюсь так будет понятнее

Comment: Добавьте код сохранения (текстом, не картинкой). И добавьте ошибку, если таковая имеется. Ту, которую вы представили, возникает из-за дебагера.

Comment: @ArchDemon Здравствуйте добавил код. Ошибка выводится в режиме дебаг

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много времени убил на то чтобы разобраться. Спасибо большое @ArchDemon за то что подсказал что копаю не туда. Во общем  с начало поменял

```
    try {
    userService.registerUser(user);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

на

```
    try {
    userService.registerUser(user);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Чтобы получить ошибки во время передачи данные из controller в service.
После этого я наконец то получил ошибку, ошибка было в валидации
мне пришлось отключить его

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

После этого я получил еще одну ошибку

```
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

Я потратил немного времени чтобы найти решение
оказывается это ошибка не было связано с кодом
Ошибка было связано с google нужно было настроить его. Вот ссылка
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps